# Why use (k+1) instead of k in numerator of BM25 scoring formula

Tags: computational-linguistics, information-retrieval

BM25 uses this nonlinear transformation to scale the term frequency:

[image]

where *x* is a term frequency. **Why is *k+1* used in numerator instead of just *k*?**

Wouldn't formula below work equally well?

[image]

It is simpler to calculate then the first formula and the resulting scaling is similar as shown on this graph:

[image]

where the first formula is drawn in red and the second in blue for k in {1, 2, 3, 4}.

**EDIT**

Is it because the first formula reduces to *1* (no scaling) for *k = 0* and the second one can't be reduced to *1*? Turning the scaling on and off could be useful in experimenting with different values of *k*, especially in the case where other formulas with their own parameters are involved.

Comment: A comment to explain why it is unclear probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I'm not sure what else I can add to my question. I would expect two kinds of answers: (1) xk/(x+k) can't be used because .... or (2) both formulas would work, but x(k+1)/(x+k) was chosen because ...